# Send Multiple XMLHTTP Requests JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Am I able to send multiple XMLHttpRequests at once? I want to get data from three urls at once and two out of the three return status code 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I able to send multiple XMLHttpRequests at once?

Yes. The browser may or may not do all three at once (some mobile browsers limit themselves to two parallel requests), but most will, and if it doesn't your code won't really notice (one of the requests will just take a while longer). Just use different [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) objects, or make multiple [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) requests.